# interrupt 21h/09h deleting entire line instead of printing stored string in the DX register

Tags: assembly

I am using emu8086. The program is intended to convert lowercase sentence into uppercase.

**int 21h/09h** is acting weird, it just deletes the whole line. I know it is supposed to output the string stored in dx but here it is behaving weirdly. I have no idea why this is happening when that part of code is executed. The rest of the code works fine. Can anyone please explain? If the question is unclear, please tell me, and I will try my best to clear it up.

```
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset str
int 21h
```

Here is the full code:

```
.model large
.data                                                            
str db 99,?,99 dup(?)
nl db 10d,13d,'$'
m1 db "Enter a sentence in lowercase: $"
m2 db "Your sentence in uppercase is: $"
.code

;//NEWLINE
newline proc
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset nl
int 21h
ret
endp

main proc

;//MAIN CODING

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

;//STRING INPUT
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset m1
int 21h
mov ah,0Ah
mov dx,offset str
int 21h
CALL newline

;//CHARACTER COUNT
mov dx,offset str
mov bx,dx
mov ah,00h
mov al,[bx+1]
mov bp,ax
mov cx,ax

;//CONVERTING LOWERCASE INTO UPPERCASE
mov si,offset str
add si,2
mov bx,0000h
mov ax,0000h
repeat:
mov bl,[si]
mov al,bl
sub al,32d
xchg bl,al
mov [si],bl
inc si
loop repeat

;//PRINTING THE RESULT
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset m2
int 21h 

;//PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
mov ah,09h                      ;THE PROBLEMATIC LINES
mov dx,offset str               ;THE PROBLEMATIC LINES
int 21h                         ;THE PROBLEMATIC LINES


;//ENDING THE PROGRAM
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: As an experiment, replace loading the addresses via "offset" with lea instructions...  If that helps, then you know that you have an origin issue (all the assemblers I've used have a side effect that a bad origin will cause offset loads to fail, but lea will still succeed).  Alternate, if you have a decent debugger, verify that the offset addresses (combined with segment) loading really do point to the data strings.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's change the input variable definition to make life easier:

```
str db 99,?,99 dup(?)
```

gets changed to:

```
str      db 99, ?, 99 dup("$")
```

Why?  String buffers in DOS are terminated with a $, so we will just initialize our buffer filled with $ so we won't have to add a $ in code.

Next, the text does not start at `str` address, but `str + 2`

```
Format of DOS input buffer:

Offset  Size    Description     (Table 01344)
00h    BYTE    maximum characters buffer can hold
01h    BYTE    (call) number of chars from last input which may be recalled
(ret) number of characters actually read, excluding CR
02h  N BYTEs   actual characters read, including the final carriage return
```

So, the first byte is the buffer size, next byte is not needed, so the string actually starts 2 bytes in!

If the buffer - `str` address starts at 300, then the address of the string is 302, make sense?

```
;//PROBLEM OCCURS HERE  
mov     ah, 09h         
mov     dx, offset str+2 ; <---- this will print the string
int     21h
```

Comment: thanks bud but i know all this and have implemented it too.. `dup(?)` actually means that the array is filled with `00h` for now or an unknown value. secondly about you asking me to add `2` to the `offset of the str`, Yes you are right and i have done that, the reason being that the first byte tells the size of buffer, second byte tells us that we do not know the number of characters which will be saved in the buffer, hence a `?`. Where i have done it if you ask?
here is the line of coding which does that    
    ';//CONVERTING LOWERCASE INTO UPPERCASE'  'mov si,offset str'  'add si,2'

Comment: why use the xchg here? Reason is that i am simply scanning each byte, replacing them by their equivalent upper character `sub al,32d` (ASCII Difference of 32 characters) and then simply replacing the original with this new one :)

Note: I have already designed a better version of my coding for upper to lower, lower to upper and for toggled case ... :P  kind of spending nights on understanding and implementing assembly :D

Comment: and oh.. the original problem of **entire line getting deleted when the final int21h is being executed** still persists :P

Answer (score 0):

Actually dup(?) does not mean fill with zeros, it means it is not initialized and the loader can fill it with whatever it wants when loading your program, but since we need to terminate our strings with a "$" we will initialize it with it to make our lives easier.

So, when I change this:

```
str db 99,?,99 dup(?)
```

To this:

```
str db 99,?,99 dup("$")
```

and this:

```
mov ah,09h       
mov dx,offset str
int 21h
```

to this:

```
mov ah,09h       
mov dx,offset str + 2
int 21h
```

We get a proper output!

[image]

Comment: thanks bud. but here is what i designed the next day only.. it also exempts symbols & numbers from being converted :P .. check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks bud. but here is what i designed the next day only.. it also exempts symbols & numbers from being converted :P

```
.model large
.data                                                            
str dw 599,?,599 dup(?)
nl db 10d,13d,'$'
m1 db "Enter a sentence in lowercase: $"
m2 db "Your sentence in UPPERCASE is: $"
.code

;//ALL THE SUB-PROCEDURES

;//NEWLINE
newline proc
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset nl
    int 21h
    ret
endp

main proc



;//MAIN CODING

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax

    ;//STRING INPUT
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset m1
    int 21h
    mov ah,0Ah
    mov dx,offset str
    int 21h
    CALL newline

    ;//PRINT PROMPT MESSAGE
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset m2
    int 21h 

    ;//CHARACTER COUNT
    mov dx,offset str
    mov bx,dx
    mov ah,00h
    mov al,[bx+1]
    mov bp,ax
    mov cx,ax

    ;//CONVERTING LOWERCASE INTO UPPERCASE
    mov si,offset str
    add si,2
    mov bx,0000h
    mov ax,0000h
    repeat:
    mov bl,[si]
    mov al,bl

    ;//IF CHARACTER OTHER THAN LOWERCASE LETTER, PRINT IT AS IT IS
    mov bp,0061h ;ASCII 'a'
    cmp bx,bp
    JL notequal
    mov bp,007Ah ;ASCII 'z'
    cmp bx,bp
    JG notequal

    sub al,32d
    xchg bl,al

    ;//PRINTING OUTPUT CHARACTER BY CHARACTER
    notequal:
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,bl
    int 21h
    inc si
    loop repeat

    ;//ENDING THE PROGRAM
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: Um, for a proper answer, you have to explain what the problem was and how you fixed it. Posting two large chunks of code does not provide any value to the next person with the same problem.